# Como funciona popUpTo y popUpToInclusive

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy trabajando con Navigation Component y por más que leo sobre estas dos propiedades no las termino de entender.

Se supone que con el `popUpTo` lo que hacemos es indicarle hasta que fragment vamos a saltar y que elimine todos los demás. Pero entonces, si por ejemplo tengo el `FragmentA` y el `FragmentB` y voy a navegar del `FragmentA` al `FragmentB`, ¿por qué, para cuando yo esté en el FragmentB y no quiera que al pulsar atrás se me vuelva a abrir el FragmentA, tengo que hacer un `popUpTo="fragmentA"`?

¿No se supone que lo que haría esto sería vaciarme la pila menos el FragmentA?

Comment: Esta pregunta sería mil veces más clara si tuviese un ejemplo mínimo verificable.

Answer (score 3):

> Se supone que con el popUpTo lo que hacemos es indicarle hasta que fragment vamos a saltar y que elimine todos los demás.

No, lo que le indicas es hasta donde debe eliminar. Te lo explicaré con código:

Imagina que el back stack es arrayList que contiene los ID de las destinations por las que has navegado

```
val backStack: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
```

entonces el popUpTo seria algo como esto

```
fun popBackStack(upTo: Int, inclusive: Boolean) {
    var index = backStack.lastIndex
    while (index >= 0) {
        if (backStack[index] == upTo) {
            if (inclusive)
                backStack.removeAt(index)
            break
        } else backStack.removeAt(index)
        index--
    }
}
```

La función real es muy similar pero con la diferencia de que no hace nada si le pasas el id de una destination que actualmente no está en el stack (la mia eliminaría todo).

### Ejemplo

Si tu navegas usando el id de una destination o el id de una action que no tiene el atributo `popUp`, entonces tendrás múltiples instancias de cada destination. Por ejemplo tu back stack podría ser este:

```
[A,B,C,B,C,A,C]
```

Ahora estás en el fragment C y navegas hasta el fragment A de esta forma: `navController.navigate(R.id.action_C_to_A)`. Digamos que esta action tiene `popUpto=B`, por lo tanto sucede lo siguiente:

primero se ejecuta `popBackStack(B, false)` y como resultado el back stack queda así:

```
[A,B,C,B]
```

luego navega al fragment A y lo agrega al back stack

```
[A,B,C,B,A]
```

cuando presionas el back button se elimina el último elemento y se carga el que ahora es el último

```
[A,B,C,B]
```

Y así sucesivamente hasta que  el back stack se vacía y en ese momento la app se cierra.

Comment: Lo entiendo, pero he estado probando con un par de activities que tengo, uno que controla el Login y el otro el Dashboard y parece ser que con los activities no funciona, es como que lo ignora y no los elimina de la pila. He tenido que terminar usando los finish() cosa que quería evitar, pero no he visto otra forma con el nav component